# How to make Discord.js bot fetch last attachment on channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make my Discord bot send the last attachment on the channel but I'm having problem with sending it.
When I use "m.attachments.first().url" it says "Unhandled promise rejection", and when I use "m.attachments.first()" it says "Cannot send an empty message".

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'test'){
message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
    const firstAttachment = messages.filter((m) => m.attachments.first().url);
    message.channel.send(firstAttachment);
})}
```

EDIT: I tried a lot of different things but the only that gave me some result was this (the result was "undefined"):

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'test'){
message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
    const att = messages.filter(m => m.attachments.size > 0);
    message.channel.send(`${att.first().attachments.url}`)
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close with your second piece of code! You just need to add another `.first()` after `attachments`.

```
    message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
        const att = messages.filter(m => m.attachments.size > 0);
        
        message.channel.send(att.first().attachments.first().url);
    });
```

You'll likely also want to make sure `att` actually has a value before sending a message, otherwise you'll get errors.